# How to pass template string in prisma raw query?

Tags: sql, nestjs, prisma

I have the below array of numbers:

```
let levels = [86, 88, 89, 90];
let levelsConverted:any = '(' + levels.join(', ') + ')';
```

Now I need to pass levelsConverted values to my sql insert query.

```
return await this.prisma.$queryRaw`
            DECLARE @levelList TABLE (id int);
            INSERT INTO @levelList(id) VALUES ${levelsConverted};
            
            SELECT * FROM Users WHERE LevelId IN (SELECT id FROM @levelList)
`;
```

when I run the code am getting the below error:

```
PrismaClientKnownRequestError:
Invalid `prisma.$queryRaw()` invocation:
Raw query failed. Code: `102`. Message: `Incorrect syntax near '@P1'.`
```

I am new to prisma orm.
I don't know how to pass the javascript variables inside sql query.
Need some valuable help.